# Unity3D: My Admob Setting window isn't showing properly

Tags: unity, android, google-play-services, admob

so i wanted to experiment with google ads using admob.
i am following the official guide from google.
i downloaded the Unity Package from official github and imported all the stuff. but i am unable to see all the options in admob settings window.
[image]

as soon as i press play button those ID field goes blank.
i reimported all the files, downgraded the version but i cant get it to work.
it keeps giving me error like assertion failed. some UI bugs. and sometime inspector freezes.

please guide me!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open Unity dashboard, create the project, link the
id's then use the scripts.

Do so then add these scripts. Watch [this](https://youtu.be/gzTs3WpzhWg) video, then if you want, copy these scripts into your project.

### SDK

Create a script, call it "sdk" then paste this:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class sdk : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsInitializationListener
{
    [SerializeField] string _androidGameId;
    [SerializeField] string _iOsGameId;
    [SerializeField] bool _testMode = true;
    [SerializeField] bool _enablePerPlacementMode = true;
    private string _gameId;

    void Awake()
    {
        InitializeAds();
    }

    public void InitializeAds()
    {
        _gameId = (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
            ? _iOsGameId
            : _androidGameId;
        Advertisement.Initialize(_gameId, _testMode, _enablePerPlacementMode, this);
    }

    public void OnInitializationComplete()
    {
        Debug.Log("Unity Ads initialization complete.");
    }

    public void OnInitializationFailed(UnityAdsInitializationError error, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Unity Ads Initialization Failed: {error.ToString()} - {message}");
    }
}
```

### Interstitial

Create a script call it "interstital" then paste this code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class interstitial : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsLoadListener, IUnityAdsShowListener
{
    [SerializeField] string _androidAdUnitId = "Interstitial_Android";
    [SerializeField] string _iOsAdUnitId = "Interstitial_iOS";
    string _adUnitId;

    void Awake()
    {
        // Get the Ad Unit ID for the current platform:
        _adUnitId = (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
            ? _iOsAdUnitId
            : _androidAdUnitId;
    }

    // Load content to the Ad Unit:
    public void LoadAd()
    {
        // IMPORTANT! Only load content AFTER initialization (in this example, initialization is handled in a different script).
        Debug.Log("Loading Ad: " + _adUnitId);
        Advertisement.Load(_adUnitId, this);
    }

    // Show the loaded content in the Ad Unit: 
    public void ShowAd()
    {
        // Note that if the ad content wasn't previously loaded, this method will fail
        Debug.Log("Showing Ad: " + _adUnitId);
        Advertisement.Show(_adUnitId, this);
    }

    // Implement Load Listener and Show Listener interface methods:  
    public void OnUnityAdsAdLoaded(string adUnitId)
    {
        // Optionally execute code if the Ad Unit successfully loads content.
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsFailedToLoad(string adUnitId, UnityAdsLoadError error, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Error loading Ad Unit: {adUnitId} - {error.ToString()} - {message}");
        // Optionally execite code if the Ad Unit fails to load, such as attempting to try again.
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowFailure(string adUnitId, UnityAdsShowError error, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Error showing Ad Unit {adUnitId}: {error.ToString()} - {message}");
        // Optionally execite code if the Ad Unit fails to show, such as loading another ad.
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowStart(string adUnitId) { }
    public void OnUnityAdsShowClick(string adUnitId) { }
    public void OnUnityAdsShowComplete(string adUnitId, UnityAdsShowCompletionState showCompletionState) { }
}
```

### Rewarded

Create a script, call it "rewarded" then paste this code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class rewarded : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsLoadListener, IUnityAdsShowListener
{
    [SerializeField] Button _showAdButton;
    [SerializeField] string _androidAdUnitId = "Rewarded_Android";
    [SerializeField] string _iOsAdUnitId = "Rewarded_iOS";
    string _adUnitId;

    void Awake()
    {
        // Get the Ad Unit ID for the current platform:
        _adUnitId = (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
            ? _iOsAdUnitId
            : _androidAdUnitId;

        //Disable button until ad is ready to show
        _showAdButton.interactable = false;
    }

    // Load content to the Ad Unit:
    public void LoadAd()
    {
        // IMPORTANT! Only load content AFTER initialization (in this example, initialization is handled in a different script).
        Debug.Log("Loading Ad: " + _adUnitId);
        Advertisement.Load(_adUnitId, this);
    }

    // If the ad successfully loads, add a listener to the button and enable it:
    public void OnUnityAdsAdLoaded(string adUnitId)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ad Loaded: " + adUnitId);

        if (adUnitId.Equals(_adUnitId))
        {
            // Configure the button to call the ShowAd() method when clicked:
            _showAdButton.onClick.AddListener(ShowAd);
            // Enable the button for users to click:
            _showAdButton.interactable = true;
        }
    }

    // Implement a method to execute when the user clicks the button.
    public void ShowAd()
    {
        // Disable the button: 
        _showAdButton.interactable = false;
        // Then show the ad:
        Advertisement.Show(_adUnitId, this);
    }

    // Implement the Show Listener's OnUnityAdsShowComplete callback method to determine if the user gets a reward:
    public void OnUnityAdsShowComplete(string adUnitId, UnityAdsShowCompletionState showCompletionState)
    {
        if (adUnitId.Equals(_adUnitId) && showCompletionState.Equals(UnityAdsShowCompletionState.COMPLETED))
        {
            Debug.Log("Unity Ads Rewarded Ad Completed");
            // Grant a reward.

            // Load another ad:
            Advertisement.Load(_adUnitId, this);
        }
    }

    // Implement Load and Show Listener error callbacks:
    public void OnUnityAdsFailedToLoad(string adUnitId, UnityAdsLoadError error, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Error loading Ad Unit {adUnitId}: {error.ToString()} - {message}");
        // Use the error details to determine whether to try to load another ad.
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowFailure(string adUnitId, UnityAdsShowError error, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Error showing Ad Unit {adUnitId}: {error.ToString()} - {message}");
        // Use the error details to determine whether to try to load another ad.
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowStart(string adUnitId) { }
    public void OnUnityAdsShowClick(string adUnitId) { }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        // Clean up the button listeners:
        _showAdButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    }
}
```

### Banner

Create a script call it banner, then paste this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class banner : MonoBehaviour
{
    // For the purpose of this example, these buttons are for functionality testing:
    [SerializeField] Button _loadBannerButton;
    [SerializeField] Button _showBannerButton;
    [SerializeField] Button _hideBannerButton;

    [SerializeField] BannerPosition _bannerPosition = BannerPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER;

    [SerializeField] string _androidAdUnitId = "Banner_Android";
    [SerializeField] string _iOsAdUnitId = "Banner_iOS";
    string _adUnitId;

    void Start()
    {
        // Disable the button until an ad is ready to show:
        _showBannerButton.interactable = false;
        _hideBannerButton.interactable = false;

        // Set the banner position:
        Advertisement.Banner.SetPosition(_bannerPosition);

        // Configure the Load Banner button to call the LoadBanner() method when clicked:
        _loadBannerButton.onClick.AddListener(LoadBanner);
        _loadBannerButton.interactable = true;
    }

    // Implement a method to call when the Load Banner button is clicked:
    public void LoadBanner()
    {
        // Set up options to notify the SDK of load events:
        BannerLoadOptions options = new BannerLoadOptions
        {
            loadCallback = OnBannerLoaded,
            errorCallback = OnBannerError
        };

        // Load the Ad Unit with banner content:
        Advertisement.Banner.Load(_adUnitId, options);
    }

    // Implement code to execute when the loadCallback event triggers:
    void OnBannerLoaded()
    {
        Debug.Log("Banner loaded");

        // Configure the Show Banner button to call the ShowBannerAd() method when clicked:
        _showBannerButton.onClick.AddListener(ShowBannerAd);
        // Configure the Hide Banner button to call the HideBannerAd() method when clicked:
        _hideBannerButton.onClick.AddListener(HideBannerAd);

        // Enable both buttons:
        _showBannerButton.interactable = true;
        _hideBannerButton.interactable = true;      
    }

    // Implement code to execute when the load errorCallback event triggers:
    void OnBannerError(string message)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Banner Error: {message}");
        // Optionally execute additional code, such as attempting to load another ad.
    }

    // Implement a method to call when the Show Banner button is clicked:
    void ShowBannerAd()
    {
        // Set up options to notify the SDK of show events:
        BannerOptions options = new BannerOptions
        {
            clickCallback = OnBannerClicked,
            hideCallback = OnBannerHidden,
            showCallback = OnBannerShown
        };

        // Show the loaded Banner Ad Unit:
        Advertisement.Banner.Show(_adUnitId, options);
    }

    // Implement a method to call when the Hide Banner button is clicked:
    void HideBannerAd()
    {
        // Hide the banner:
        Advertisement.Banner.Hide();
    }

    void OnBannerClicked() { }
    void OnBannerShown() { }
    void OnBannerHidden() { }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        // Clean up the listeners:
        _loadBannerButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        _showBannerButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        _hideBannerButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    }
}
```

**Do watch the video because it does contain some changes to the script and show to use.**

Comment: the video you linked shows Unity's own ad implementation right?
but i am using admob SDK from google